# Lotusscript to open and launch an excel file xlsm report in Mac

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I am working on a VBA Script in Excel and Lotusscript to work in Mac. In VBA Excel for Mac the following file system object, ActiveX, ODBC, OLE, DLL, Shell etc. all do not work in Mac. I have found solution and alternative to all the VBA scripts and now they are all working in Mac.

Just one thing in Lotusscript I am finding an alternative to work in Mac. I have written the following below in lotusscript but does not seem to work in Mac. I am finding an alternative to make it work in Mac. I want to launch and open an excel file (xlsm) report in Mac by using a lotusscript.

```
Dim XlApp as Variant
Dim xFile as String
xFile = "/Users/Shared/Temp/my file.xlsm"
Set XlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XlApp.Open.Workbooks xFile
XlApp.Visible = True
```

Any alternative to this in lotusscript to work in Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but there is a workaround using AppleScript https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6828238?start=0&tstart=0.